# Would serial killers be a thing In a world where duels to the death are perfectly legal?

Tags: internal-consistency, psychology

In this world, people have the legal right to fight anyone to the death, for any reason, as long as the fights are done before an official whose sole job is to regulate these duels. The officials in questions are plentiful, and it rarely takes more than a couple of hours for the fight to happen. It should also be noted that it is explicitly not allowed to refuse such a duel.

The duels aren't about torture, however; After a while, if the fight is clearly one-sided and there are no chances for one side to take back the advantage, the official will compel, using force if necessary, the losing side to surrender and be killed.

So my question is : In a world where murders are practically regulated, would there be serial killers and the like? By this I mean, would twisted people feel the need to do home invasions and kidnappings and the like when you can pretty much legally sate your bloodlust against anyone at any time?

Comment: pretty sure they will still around like baron de raiss or marie antoniette even jack the ripper i believe they still do duel in that timeline though not every duel is to the death unless trial by combat, not every serial killer is duelist or have the strength to overpower people so some wont use a fair way to kill people like poison and the like.

Comment: Never heard of duels for matters of honor?

Comment: btw i dont downvote you, and when i say duel here it include sword duel and gun duel/gun fight like usual cowboy thing.

Comment: @LiJun What would stop the serial killer from specifically targeting people who aren't strong enough to defend themselves in a duel?

Comment: ah i mean elisabeth batori there not marie antoniette

Comment: dont understimate noob in duel, many master duelist die from noob because noob will use trickery or find a loophole or just goes yolo to kill you even if you are stronger and both end up dying. because in duel you also  get a chance to get killed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course. A fair fight is dangerous. It's  a really bad way to kill people while avoiding death yourself. The typical serial killer doesn't just want to kill people, or even specific types of people. They want to kill, possibly specific types of, people in specific ways, very likely not condoned by a dueling referee, under circumstances in which they are in total control. It is the same for predators of all types--a predator who goes in for a fair fight quickly becomes a dead predator. The ones who live to predate another day do so by carefully stacking the deck in their favor.

Answer (score 0):

Why would I duel someone? Duels are only a question of honour...he stole my girl after she cheated on me with him....I'm gonna stomp his face and squirt his brains out of his cranium to prove that I'm not a cuckhold.

But what if I don't feel hatred for anyone? What if I wanted to kill for money? People hunt animals for fun, and some soldiers say the best feeling in the world is hunting humans.

What if I'm a a guy who hates gays and I download grindr a gay meeting app to get other men to invite me in their homes for some sex but instead I blow their brains off with a gun and steal everything they have in their homes or just go away?

What if instead I'm a necrophile and I like to have sex with girls....when they are dead and I download tinder and find a lot of victims?

I could make an infinite list of reasons and ways to murder people serially and not get caught.